# Here map. Android mobile SDK. Zoom controls

Tags: here-api, samsung-mobile-sdk

How do I enable Zoom controls on the map when using android mobile SDK?
Thanks
Eugene

Answer (score 1):

The default MapView and MapFragments provided by the HERE SDK do not contain the traditional + and - zoom controls. Please add an Android button to handle the click and hold commands to zoom. We usually zoom or the map by doing the following:

To zoom in:
map.setZoomLevel( map.getZoomLevel() * 1.05 );

To zoom out:
map.setZoomLevel( map.getZoomLevel() / 1.05 );

The developer is free to control the speed of the zoom in and out as per their user experience.

Adding general UI controls are on our bucket list of items to consider adding as part of the SDK. We need to carefully design it so it can be customizable by developers and hence "generic" controls have not been added.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to do a zoom using 2 finger tap ? 
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-gestures.html